# Formatting Dates from Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, strptime

[image: Screenshot of my code]

I am trying to convert the date format in an array from '2018-03-02' (Y-m-d) to '20180302'. I would think a for loop through the dates array would change each date, however, I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not list

I would like a new array of dates that are formatted using "Y%m%d"

Comment: you run in loop and you work with single date - you have to use `date` instead of `dates`  - `new_date =  datetime.datetime.striptime(date, "Y%m%d")` - and you have to append `new_date` to list `newdates`

Comment: put code as text - we ca't copy code from screenshot to modify it.

Comment: you have string - you could use `replace('-', '')`

Comment: you have two-dimesional array - maybe you need list with dates.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues here. Firstly, in your first line of code, you're actually declaring a tuple of three lists, with each list holding one string in date format. What you probably want to be doing is:

```
dates = ["2019-04-21", "2018-03-05", "2016,01,01"]
```

Secondly, I'm not entirely sure why you're converting to an numpy array; it doesn't seem necessary in your use case. Thirdly, the dates, as you've provided them, are strings, not datetimes that the datetime library can work with; honestly, if all your dates look like this, you probably don't need to convert them to datetimes and back. You could just replace the "-" or "," with an empty string, which would effectively remove the "-"s and ","s from the string. Fourthly, you're only updating the newdates variable to hold the last date; if you want it to hold all the dates, you're going to need a new list. Finally, in your for loop, you're using the dates variable (which is now a list of dates) rather than date (which is a single date string). All put together, this should look like:

```
newdates = []
for date in dates:
  newdates.append(date.replace("-","").replace(",","")
```

This could also be done more "pythonically" in a list comprehension:

```
newdates = [date.replace("-","").replace(",","") for date in dates]
```

Comment: one date in question has `,` instead of `-`. You could add `.replace(',', '')`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice. Updated the answer correspondingly.